# Pandas dataframe encode Categorical variable with thousands of unique values

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data

I have a dataframe about data on schools for a few thousands cities. The school is the row identifier and the city is encoded as follow:

```
school city          category   capacity
1      azez6576sebd  45         23
2      dsqozbc765aj  12         236
3      sqdqsd12887s  8          63 
4      azez6576sebd  7          234 
...
```

How can I convert the city variable to numeric knowing that I have a few thousand cities ? I guess one-hot encoding is not appropriate as I will have too many columns. What is the general approach to convert categorical variable with thousand of levels to numeric ?

Thank you.

Comment: You will have a few thousand columns. That is still manageable. If needed, you can use a SparseDataFrame to hold your OHE values.

Answer (score 27):

You can using category dtype in sklearn , it should be [`labelencoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)

```
df.city=df.city.astype('category').cat.codes
df
Out[385]: 
   school  city  category  capacity
0       1     0        45        23
1       2     1        12       236
2       3     2         8        63
3       4     0         7       234
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I thought at first but then the variable would be considered as ordinal by ML algorithms 0 < 1 < 2... which makes no cense in this case The city  category is unordered nominal.

Comment: yes, I agree with roqds, this doesn't seem to resolve this issue because it does not map that feature into n-dimensional space. I am trying to understand how to solve the same problem too

Comment: I performed a number of test to understand if this encoding is deterministic in terms of value order (or perhaps something else?), it seems like the answer is yes, anyone thinks otherwise?

Answer (score 5):

A few thousand columns is still manageable in the context of ML classifiers. Although you'd want to watch out for the [*curse of dimensionality*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality).

That aside, you wouldn't want a `get_dummies` call to result in a memory blowout, so you could generate a `SparseDataFrame` instead -

```
v = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('school').city, sparse=True)
v

        azez6576sebd  dsqozbc765aj  sqdqsd12887s
school                                          
1                  1             0             0
2                  0             1             0
3                  0             0             1
4                  1             0             0

type(v)
pandas.core.sparse.frame.SparseDataFrame
```

You can generate a sparse matrix using `sdf.to_coo` -

```
v.to_coo()

<4x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.uint8'>'
    with 4 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

Comment: ok thanks I didn't know this function I will try... And then I convert back this Coordinate sparse matrix to dataframe like this pd.SparseDataFrame(v.to_coo()) and concat it to my initial dataframe ?

Comment: @coldspeed, I just tried to do this on my dataframe but it doesn't seem to help. It was running for a while (maybe 30 minutes or so) and then I got the MemoryError message

Comment: @mkheifetz the sparse API is pretty sad right now. Stick to scipy until it's fixed.

Comment: @coldspeed, can you please explain, so how would I go about resolving this problem?

Answer (score 2):

An optimal way, that's used in production ML systems & Kaggle competitions is to use embeddings, like their target statistics. So for a binary target variable you can calculate the following for each of the distinct categorical values.

1) No of positive labels
2) No of Negative labels
3) Ratio

Here's a video explaining it - [Large-Scale Learning - Dr. Mikhail Bilenko](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=7sZeTxIrnxs)

Hash encoders are also suitable for your situation of 'city' column having a few thousand distinct values. This method scales pretty well. You need to specify the number of binary output columns that you want as output.

Another option for supervised learning cases is Target Encoder or James Stein encoder. This technique replaces each category with the average value of the target for rows with the category. But if your dataset sample isnt very large, and you have only a few examples per category this method may not be very useful.

Here's a helpful blogpost that I referred to - [Encoding Categorical Variables](https://kiwidamien.github.io/encoding-categorical-variables.html)